# What should I write in the experience section of CV?

Tags: cv, internship

I have recently graduated with a BSc degree in Physics. I haven't had any internship before. Well, all internships last summer were cancelled because of covid. Now, I am applying for few internships for the summer of 2021. What should I put in the experiences section of the CV? Or, should I remove the whole section?

Comment: Do you have any sort of extracurricular activities?

Comment: @zhantongz I have but I doubt that will be helpful for a physics internship

Comment: Any physics or math project courses? Even CS?

Comment: @Buffy Yes I have done labs. For example, electronics labs( measure characteristics of transistors/ make adders, counters, 7-segment display, mux, demux, registors etc with digital ics), optics labs (biprism, spectrometers, newtons rings, diffraction, interference pattens and so on). We had to take at least two lab courses in each semester. I sure have done a few interesting experiments. Can I mention these as experince?

Comment: Yes, you can mention them, but don't oversell them. You are seeking deeper experience, not claiming that you already have it. This is in line with the purpose of an internship.

Answer (score -1):

In the experience section of the CV, there should be (relatively) relevant experience to the job/internship you are applying to.

It is not clear what you want to write in the experience section. Of course, you shouldn't have a section labelled "experience" and then nothing in it. I would also advise against putting irrelevant experience in this section (e.g. babysitting 5 years ago) which would have the same effect to me.

Writing "internship in [place] on [topic] *cancelled because of coronavirus*" would not feel right to me neither, especially if this is the only item in "experience".

Keep the CV short and simple and then address in your cover letter the fact that you didn't do an internship at the end of your Bsc degree because of the coronavirus.